# Local composer package in Laravel does not match the expected JSON scheme

Tags: json, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to load a local package into my Laravel 8 project, but am getting the following error in `./composer.json`:

```
  "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:                                                     
   - repositories[5].url : The property url is required                                                          
   - repositories[5].type : Does not have a value in the enumeration ["composer"]                                
   - repositories[5].type : Does not have a value in the enumeration ["vcs","github","git","gitlab","bitbucket"  
  ,"git-bitbucket","hg","fossil","perforce","svn"]                                                               
   - repositories[5].type : Does not have a value in the enumeration ["artifact"]                                
   - repositories[5].type : Does not have a value in the enumeration ["pear"]                                    
   - repositories[5].package : The property package is required                                                  
   - repositories[5].type : Does not have a value in the enumeration ["package"]                                 
   - repositories[5] : Failed to match at least one schema                                                       
   - repositories[5] : Must contain no more than 1 properties                                                    
   - repositories[5].type : String value found, but a boolean is required                                        
   - repositories[5].type : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]                                     
   - repositories[5].path : String value found, but a boolean is required                                        
   - repositories[5].path : Does not have a value in the enumeration [false]
```

My `composer.json` file contains the following for the require and repos section:

```json
"repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:company/pkg-fudge-inbound-management-bridge.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:company/pkg-inbound-management.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:company/pkg-blog.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:company/pkg-credit-score.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "git@github.com:company/pkg-policies.git"
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "path": "/Users/ryanholton/Sites/laravel-packages/pkg-cms"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.11",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "8.60.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
    "company/pkg-fudge-inbound-management-bridge": "1.1.*",
    "company/pkg-inbound-management": "2.0.*",
    "company/pkg-blog": "1.4.*",
    "company/pkg-credit-score": "1.2.*",
    "company/pkg-policies": "1.0.*",
    "company/pkg-cms": "*"
}
```

Not sure why I'm getting this error, never had it with local packages before, what am I missing?

Comment: have you checked your path ? try to add your full path like  => "C:/Users/ryanholton..."

Comment: Did you check the given configuration for problem? It looks pretty obvious to me that a JSON file should not start with `"repositories"`

Answer (score 0):

As error said your last item in `repositories` array should look like:

```
{
  "type": $type,
  "url": //here you have to define url
  "path": "/Users/ryanholton/Sites/laravel-packages/pkg-cms"
}
```

and your `$type` variable should have 1 of the values below:

```
"vcs","github","git","gitlab","bitbucket" ,"git-bitbucket","hg","fossil","perforce","svn","composer","artifact","pear","package"
```

If you are trying yo add package, then `$type` should be `"package"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
{
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "name/example-package",
                "version": "dev-master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "git@github.com:company/pkg-policies.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "dev-master"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is "this"? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

You need to define like this

```php
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "/Users/ryanholton/Sites/laravel-packages/pkg-cms"
        }
    ],
}
```

So it seems you just need to replace `path` with `url`.

Comment: Please add some more information to your answer such that others can learn from it. The part you've shown looks exactly like the part from the original configuration to me

Comment: @NicoHaase `"path":` has been changed to `url:`

Comment: @NicoHaase, I explained clearly that path has to be replaced with url, what else would you like me to explain?

Comment: Sorry, I did only see `"type": "path"` and this confused me, as you told to replace `path` with `url` and there's sill `path` in that value